# Find the primitive ideal for a given Galois extension.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

Could $E=\{a_0*e+a_1*x+a_2*x^2|a_0,a_1,a_2∈\mathbb Q\}$ $(x^3=e)$be an extention field for $\mathbb Q$? If yes, what could the corresponding $f(x)∈\mathbb Q[x]$ be for $E\cong \mathbb Q[x]/<f(x)>$?

Comment: $E$ is not a field

Comment: Yes, you are right, $E$ is not a field, which implies that $f(x)$ should be reducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about extension fields of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ doesn't really make sense since $\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is not a field, but I assume you meant extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$. Also since $x^3=1$ in $E$, we see that $E \cong \mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle x^3-1 \rangle$ which is not a field since $x^3-1$ is reducible.

Comment: I'm thinking that Q(zeta)={a_0*1+a_1*zeta|a_0,a_1∈Q}, so there's no need to have a zeta^2 term since zeta^2 can be expressed as zeta^2=-1-zeta, which is not in the form that I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry you are right, I edited.

Comment: So since $E$ is not a field, $f(x)$ would be reducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$? More precisely $f(x)=x^3-1$ is what I want based on the property that $g^3=e$? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. And $ f(x)=x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$.